# Como ajustar uma imagem no cabeçalho de um html?

Tags: html

Eu estou tentando ajustar uma imagem em um cabeçalho em um arquivo `html`, porém, só estou conseguindo ajustar o tamanho. Como eu posso mover a imagem um pouco mais para a esquerda e deixar alinhada com o título?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu `html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<style>
div.cabecalho {
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #1659bf;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #0f4098;
}
</style>

<div class="cabecalho">
    <img src="Markdown/Cabeçalhos/IPEAlogoBranco.png" width="245" height="180"> 
        Pesquisa Mensal de Serviços | <strong>PMS</strong>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Para este caso faça uso de Flexbox**

Caixa flexíveis têm diversas utilidades, como o poder de se ajustar à diversas resoluções e definir alinhamentos especiais baseados em: tamanho, espaço e texto.

Elementos do tipo `<div>` costumam por padrão receber o parâmetro `display: block`, o que pode dificultar o alinhamento de filhos.

No seu exemplo, para alinharmos o logo ao texto e quaisquer outros elementos do cabeçalho devemos atribuir, à classe mãe destes, o padrão `display: flex`.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
<style>
div.cabecalho {
    font-size: 250%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #1659bf;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #0f4098;
    width: 100%; /* isso será necessário, uma vez o display passa a ser flexível e não mais em bloco */
    display: flex; /* atribui as características flexíveis à divisão */
    align-items: center; /* Responsavel por alinhar todo o conteúdo filho desta divisão ao centro, de acordo com a perspectiva vertical */
}
</style>

<div class="cabecalho">
    <img src="Markdown/Cabeçalhos/IPEAlogoBranco.png" width="245" height="180"> 
    <span>Pesquisa Mensal de Serviços | <strong>PMS</strong></span>
</div>
```

Você também pode usar o atributo `"justify-content"` para fazer o alinhamento no eixo horizontal desta divisão.

**Nota**: Veja que eu incluí o título e a tag `<strong>` à um `<span>`, isto porquê caixas flexíveis lidam com seus filhos diretos, então se faz necessário termos todo o texto atribuído a elementos diretamente ligados à classe mãe.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Mas não ficou do jeito que eu gostaria, porque a imagem ficou completamente alinhada à esquerda e a imagem não ficou alinhada com o texto. Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Disponha. Antes de mais nada, veja se aqui temos o resultado que você precisa: https://codepen.io/gitBiohazard/pen/OJxWvBd

Comment: Muito obrigado!